# Dynamics AX 2012 - Positions in BOM

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++

I need help not with code but with conception. I BOM table there ale BOMs with field Position. I need to 'slice' this field into each position for example BOM position "A1-A3, 45" should be exported into excel like this:

- BOMid A1
- BOMid A2
- BOMid A3
- BOMid 45

How to do this without using a lot of memory, creating new tables?

Comment: I do not understand the question, do you want to filter the BOM records on field Position? Do you already know how you want to do the Excel export?

Comment: Rather copy BOM record with each split position.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at the data import/export entity for bill of material lines and add some parsing logic for the text in field Position to split one `BOM` record into several records in the staging table. The data from the staging table could then be exported into Excel.